# tomcat6: cannot create directory for logging in linux

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, java.util.logging

i use ubuntu 9.04 for testing platform. I have created a webapp that log a hardcoded string whenever someone visit index.jsp. I have enable SECURITY_MANAGER in /etc/init.d/tomcat6. And I have grant permission for the webapp named w1 with

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/w1/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

however, when i access the index.jsp with a browser, a

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Log/10127-2010-10-14.log (No such
>   file or directory)

is presented in catalina.out. The situation is that the directory of Log is not exist nor the log file.

If I create the directory myself, the log file will be created but with no context inside.

And I found it runs successfully in tomcat5.5 in another 8.04 box and tomcat6 in windows xp box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the default logger?

```
<!-- Application context below -->
<Context path="/manager" docBase="/opt/tomcat6/webapps/manager" privileged="true" debug="0">
<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="example.com._manager" suffix=".txt" timestamp="true"/>
</Context>
```

Inside your server.xml.

Yucca